# couldn't find file error in application.js with Sprockets on rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, sprockets

Hi I got the error `Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery-fileupload/basic.js'` on Rails 4.1.5

I googled for some related questions, but couldn't find the solution.

### application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/tmpl
```

And I use rbenv and the gem `/jquery-fileupload-rails-0.4.1` structure is

### ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jquery-fileupload-rails-0.4.1/vendor/assets/javascripts

```
.
└── jquery-fileupload
    ├── basic.js
    ├── cors
    │   ├── jquery.postmessage-transport.js
    │   └── jquery.xdr-transport.js
    ├── index.js
    ├── jquery.fileupload-fp.js
    ├── jquery.fileupload-ui.js
    ├── jquery.fileupload.js
    ├── jquery.iframe-transport.js
    ├── locale.js
    └── vendor
        ├── canvas-to-blob.js
        ├── jquery.ui.widget.js
        ├── load-image.js
        └── tmpl.js
```

When I ran `rake assets:precompile --trace`

I got the following error message

```
/Users/hsu-wei-cheng/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: already initialized constant Mime::PDF
/Users/hsu-wei-cheng/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: previous definition of PDF was here
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery-fileupload/basic.js'
  (in /Users/hsu-wei-cheng/workspace/Rails/dqa_dev_server/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:18)
/Users/hsu-wei-cheng/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:106:in `resolve'
/Users/hsu-wei-cheng/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:146:in `require_asset'
/Users/hsu-wei-cheng/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/spro
```

### GEMFILE

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jquery.fileupload-rails', "~> 1.10.0"
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'


gem "bootstrap-sass", "~> 3.1.1"
gem "compass-rails"
gem "therubyracer"
gem "execjs"

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
```

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: Of course, I restarted it many times

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please share repo link? on my email? So i can take look of your code

Comment: https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example

Comment: Or you can take look at this too.

Comment: Can it be that you have gem 'jquery.fileupload-rails' instead of gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'?